# Stack-overflow Exception no objeto ServiceHost

Tags: c#, web-service, wcf

Eu tenho uma simples implementação de *webservice*. Depois de anos do software em uso, começou a estourar exceção no objeto *ServiceHost*.

```
try
            {
                using (this._host = new ServiceHost(_receiver, new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8000")))
                {

                    this._host.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                    this._host.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                    var binding = new NetTcpBinding
                    {
                        CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                        OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                        SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                        ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),

                        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                        MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
                        MaxBufferSize = 2147483647
                    };

                    //notice the NetTcpBinding?  This allows programs instead of web stuff
                    // to communicate with each other
                    this._host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMessageReceiver), binding, "ISubscribe");


                    this._host.Opened += host_Opened;
                    this._host.Closed += host_Closed;
                    this._host.Faulted += host_Faulted;
                    this._host.Open();

                    this.LogMessage("Canal Aberto");
                    string tmp = Console.ReadLine();
                    while (tmp != "EXIT")
                    {
                        tmp = Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
                    this._host.Close();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.LogMessage(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Normalmente esse tipo de exceção ocorre em recursão, ou em código mal implementado, mas a exceção aponta para a linha onde está o `using`. Isso pode ser algum problema na configuração do *WebService*?

> ```
> System.StackOverflowException   
> HResult=0x800703E9  
> Message=Exception_WasThrown
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No fim, descobri o motivo do erro sozinho. Existia uma outra exceção que estourava com frequência: addressalreadyinuseexception. Ela apenas não borbulhava para cima, por algum motivo. Então após isso vinha o Stackoverflow.

O problema foi corrigido alterando o endereço da porta tcp, conforme esse link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b86df98d-37d1-4291-9a63-4a6019329dec/wcf-there-is-already-a-listener-on-ip-endpoint-0000808?forum=wcf